# iterrows a dataframe and convert the list of dictionary to a new dictionary with columns as keys python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, and I need to use iterrows to convert the dataframe to dictionary that columns names as the keys and values are the original dataframe list corresponding to each column name.

Dataframe like

```
   name  age gender
0  Mary  20   F
1  Sam   27   M
2  Jake  15   M
```

iterrows will give a list of dictionary as

```
[{0:name  Mary age 20 gender F}, {1:name Sam age 27 M}, ....]
```

So now how can I turn it into like this:

```
{'name':['Mary','Sam','Jake'...],'age':[20,27,15], 'gender':[F,M,M]....}
```

What I can think now is to extract values of each column and put them into multiple lists and then convert these lists into a dictionary.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the pandas dataframe `to_dict` function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Mary", "Sam", "Jake"], 
    "age": [20,27, 15], 
    "gender": ["F", "M", "M"]
})

df.to_dict(orient="list")
>>> {'name': ['Mary', 'Sam', 'Jake'],
 'age': [20, 27, 15],
 'gender': ['F', 'M', 'M']}
```